# Error: "Unable to get local issuer certificate" when running vscode with github copilot on wsl2

Tags: github

I'm runnign vscode with gitub co-pilot on Windows 10 and WSL2. Everything worked on both until today. All of a sudden, when opening a WSL2 workspace, I'm getting an error with github copilot initialization:

```
Error sending telemetry FetchError: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at fetch (/home/XXX/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.176.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:99:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at cachingFetch (/home/XXX/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.176.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:288:16)
    at DU.fetch (/home/XXX/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.176.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:78:22) {
  type: 'system',
  _name: 'FetchError',
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
```